# How can I echo out all MySQL table titles in a database, by a while-loop in php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I figured that I can select all tables within a database by using this `MySQL` query

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('columnA')
           AND TABLE_SCHEMA='YourDatabase';
```

So how can I echo out each of these table titles in a while loop?

Obviously I can't go by the usual `$row['something']`  since these are not rows but table titles...

Answer (score 3):

The column name you are looking for is `TABLE_NAME`; and you get one row per table - so you *can* do it the usual way.

Besides that you could always use the index of the column when using one of the fetch functions that do not return an associative array/object.

Comment: So I could just echo out $row[TABLE_NAME]?

Comment: You'd quote the array index but yes, you do that within a loop fetching the rows.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I have to leave the comp for a while now, so I'll look into it when I get back in a few hours! Cheers

Comment: Could you just help me again? I can't make this work....

`$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("ropox", $con);
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('id') AND TABLE_SCHEMA='products'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 echo $row["TABLE_NAME"]. " " ;
}
?>`

- Sorry for this crappy code layout... Don't know how to make it look good here in comments...